# Correct way of handling sessions in PHP

Tags: php, session, web-applications

I am using PHP 5 based web application without any framework, all of my admin page and user page has the code below to handle the session. Is it correct way of handling sessions? or any best way to prevent user entering home page after logout? Please suggest us.

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION))
{
?>

<html>...</html>

<?php
}
else {
echo 'Session expired';
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think isset() isnt accurate. You may want to use isset($_SESSION['var']) instead.

Comment: exactly as I suggested in my answer @Zapp is right.

Comment: try and validate and answer if you found it useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be shorter in this instance to just do:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['whatever']))
    die("Session Expired");
?>
<html>..etc.
```

You don't need to wrap a whole bunch of script with `if/else`.

This question is however, off topic because it's opinion-based and not specifically about a technical issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you always have to start with `session_start()` and as a result the variable `$_SESSION` might be set.

I suggest to store a token to actually show whether or not the user is authenticated so that once the session is destroyed.

**Code Snippet**

```
    <?php

        session_start();

        if ($_POST["username"] == "admin" && $_POST["password"] == sha1("password")):


            $_SESSION["authorized"] = true;
            $_SESSION["id"] = session_regenerate_id();

        endif;
    ?>
```

In this case you can check if the session exist then if the user is authenticated, it is a good practice to regenerate the session id too.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION) && $_SESSION["authorized"] == true):
        /* What you plan to do here */
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Probably `if(!empty($_SESSION["authorized"])) :` would suffice. Since in your scenario `$_SESSION["authorized"]` is `bool` so you really only have to check that it is not empty.

Comment: this make sense @Rasclatt, `empty()` will do but I don't really like to use it as many developers don't know the extends of what is considered has empty for that function.

Comment: Also, since `sha1("password")` would be like `5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8` how could `$_POST["password"] == sha1("password")`? The user would have to type something like `5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8` in this scenario?

Comment: because the `sha1` is sent via `$_POST` not the actual password. this is just a simple example to show the principle not rocking hard code the question is not about security but how to check session variables.

Answer (score -1):

you're on the right track

```
<?php

    if(isset($_SESSION))
    {
    ?>

    <html>...</html>

    <?php
    }
    else {

echo 'Session expired';
```

i would organize your lines to be a little more code friendly

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION)) {
?>

<html>...</html>

<?php
    } else {
    echo 'Session expired';
}
```

you also don't need to specify `<?php;` in your `php.ini` file 
you can set it so you could just use `<?;` once you've made the change
you need to restart apache (service or `/etc/init.d/httpd` restat or windows 
 find xampp for instance and restart apache.

Comment: You seem to be missing 2 lines from the end of that code :P